# How to write json string with utf16 characters in it

Tags: c++, json, utf-16

I'm trying to figure out how to get utf16 characters in my json string.  This is my json:

```
ourWideStringClass jsonNoError("{    \
    \"type\" : \"ROI\", \
    \"m_position\" : { \
        \"m_x\" : 16, \
        \"m_y\" : 32, \
        \"m_z\" : 0 \
    }, \
    \"m_size\" : { \
        \"m_width\" : 64, \
        \"m_height\" : 128, \
        \"m_depth\" : 3 \
    } \
    } ");
```

So if I have the following utf16, I'm not sure how to put that in the above.  I know I can't put 0x9CE5 in the json, like by replacing 128 with 0x9CE5.  I'm not sure what to do.  Any ideas?

I was reading [encoding U](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx). I'm not sure if I can use the escape U in my json string or how to do that.  Would it be \U"m_x"  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have the [`U+9CE5` character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9ce5/index.htm) as a part of a string within JSON, you can do so by **encoding it as `\u9ce5`**, e.g.:

```
"key": "before\u9ce5after"
```

**Alternatively, you can include this character *unencoded* in your JSON**.

Please refer to [json.org](http://json.org/) for JSON syntax, e.g.:

```
"key": "before鳥after"
```

---

Please note that the term *"UTF-16 character"* is *not* correct. UTF-16 doesn't define any characters — it's a specification how to *encode Unicode characters*. The characters themselves (or codepoints) are defined by the Unicode standard, and a *whole* string of Unicode characters may be encoded as UTF-16, UTF-8 or via other encoding schemes.

So *all of your JSON* is in *some* encoding (e.g. in UTF-16), *not* just separate characters.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm planning on processing the entire json string as wchar_t*, read into a wstream.  I just need to test with an actual utf16 part in it.

Comment: If I'm putting it in this line, do you think I'm doing the utf16 char correctly?  It's an escaped c++ string.  "{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"\u9ce5\"},\n"

Comment: when I do wcout for my json, it's showing ? for u9ce5.  Maybe there's something wrong?

Comment: `"{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"\u9ce5\"}` - this should result in a valid JSON, but note that C++ interprets `\u9ce5` when parsing the string literal. So the actual JSON string will contain this character *unencoded*. If you'd like JSON string to actually contain the escaped character, you need to escape the backslash by doubling it, i.e. `"{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"\\u9ce5\"}` (note the doubled `\` before `u`).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I have another question here if you're interested.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43309439/json-string-with-utf16-char-cannot-convert-from-const-char-566-to-stdbasi

Comment: @Alexshersterov - BTW, when I try this:   L"{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":L\"\\u9CE5\"},\n" the json isn't valid.  When I take out the extra L before \"\\u9ce5, cout-ing the json shows "\u9CE5", but I would expect it to show the Japanese character.  I have the extra slash to escape the \u as you can see.