# json string with utf16 char cannot convert from 'const char [566]' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'

Tags: json, utf-16, c++98

I have json that needs to test a string with a utf16 wide char in it but I get the following error message:

```
\..\test\TestClass.cpp(617): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [566]' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'


     with
2>          [
2>              _Elem=wchar_t,
2>              _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>,
2>              _Ax=std::allocator<wchar_t>
2>          ]
2>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

This is my json:

```
static std::wstring& BAD_JSON5_missingComma_multipleNewlines_Utf16MixedDosAndUnixLineEndings()
    {
        static std::wstring j =
        "{\n"           <=VS squigly says error on this line
            "\"header\":{\n"
                "\"version\":{\"major\":1,\"minor\":0,\"build\":0}\n"
            "},\n"
            "\"body\":{\n"
                "\"string\":{\"type\":\"OurWideStringClass\",\"value\":\"foo\"},\n\n\n\n"
                "\"int\":[\n"
                    "{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"\\u9CE5\"},\n"
                    "{\"type\":\"Int\",\"value\":5678}\n"
                "],\n"
                "\"double\":{\"type\":\"Double\",\"value\":12.34},\n"
                "\"path1\":[\n"
                    "{\n"
                        "\"string\":{\"type\":\"OurWideStringClass\",\"value\":\"bar\"},\r\n"
                        "\"int\":[\n"
                            "{\"type\":\"Int\"\"value\":7},\n"
                            "{\"type\":\"Int\",\"value\":11}\n"
                        "]\n"
                    "},\n"
                    "{\n"
                        "\"string\":{\"type\":\"OurWideStringClass\",\"value\":\"top\"},\n"
                        "\"int\":[\n"
                            "{\"type\":\"Int\",\"value\":13},\r\n"
                            "{\"type\":\"Int\",\"value\":41}\n"
                        "]\n"
                    "}\n"
                "],\n"
                "\"path2\":{\n"
                    "\"int\":{\"type\":\"Int\",\"value\":-1234},\n"
                    "\"double\":{\"type\":\"Double\",\"value\":-1.234}\r\n"
                "}\n"
            "}\n"
        "}\n"; <=double clicking build error goes to this line

        return j;
    }
```

This is how it's used

```
OurWideStringClass slxStJson5 = BAD_JSON5_missingComma_multipleNewlines_Utf16MixedDosAndUnixLineEndings();
std::wistringstream ssJsonMissingCommaUtf16Newlines(slxStJson5);
```

I thought I had the wchar_t covered with std::wstring in my json.  Any ideas what's the issue? you can see my utf16 character in \u9ce5.  This is the key to this test.

I looked at this [c2440](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2440) but don't see what they are referring to in the resolution with regard to UDT.

I was looking at this [which puts an L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810343/is-a-wide-character-string-literal-starting-with-l-like-lhello-world-guarantee)  in front of it, but with escaped c string, I'm not sure where to put the L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::wstring` cannot be initialized from a [narrow string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) like `"my string"`, hence the compilation error.

You can initialize a `std::wstring` from a [wide string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) — its syntax includes the **`L` prefix before the opening quote,** e.g. `L"my string"`.

As you are using string literal concatenation, **you need to prefix all the string literals with `L`**, i.e.:

```
static std::wstring j =
    L"{\n"
        L"\"header\":{\n"
            L"\"version\":{\"major\":1,\"minor\":0,\"build\":0}\n"
        L"},\n"
    ...
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  When I do a wcout of the json, without ":L\"\\u9CE5\"},\n", it's not showing the Japanese character.  It's showing "\u9CE5.  Is that incorrect?  When I add the L..... ":L\"\\u9ce5, the json is invalid close to there.  Any ideas?  I put the L's before all the lines like you say to do there.

Comment: do you see my comment there?

Comment: `When I do a wcout of the json, without ":L\"\\u9CE5\"},\n", it's not showing the Japanese character. It's showing "\u9CE5. Is that incorrect?` — no, this is correct: the symbol is encoded as a Unicode sequence in JSON, but it still represents the `Han Character 'bird'`, and any sane JSON parser will interpret it as such.